# File loading works before but not after IntelliJ IDEA builds JAR artifact

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

The resource/file loading, which happens to be loading a TTF file, ceases to work after building the program as a Jexecutable JAR artifact. Usually, in IntelliJ IDEA, making the program and then running it results in the fonts being loaded correctly, but running the IntelliJ generated executable JAR gives file not found errors.

My artifact creation is set up as such:

[image: IntelliJ Project Structure Artifact Settings]

My project is organized in the following fashion:

[image: IntelliJ Project Structure]

Looking into the generated executable JAR file with WinRAR indicates that there are three folders in the main directory, com. META-INF, and res, each containing their expected contents, yet the program does not work.

The code to load the file is as follows:

```
    try
    {
        System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on");
        System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");

        File file = new File("res/font.ttf");
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file);
    }
    /** redacted catch blocks **/
```

Comment: Have you tried using `getClass()#getResourceAsStream("/res/font.ttf")`?

Comment: I will try this but I cannot figure out how to read in an InputStream as a file. All of the solutions I have found via googling seem over-complicated and suggest using Guava, which is not an option for me.

Comment: I figured out that font creation can simply take an input stream as an argument instead of me having to turn an input stream into a file. Thank you for your help. This makes the executable jar work, but now the fonts don't work when running in IntelliJ. This seems like a silly problem. I never encountered an issue doing the same thing in Eclipse. Do you know why IntelliJ does this. How do people solve this?

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with intellij, but I "think" the directory needs to be marked in same way to allow it to be included within the IDEs classpath...maybe...possibly...